# How do I get my laptop screen backlight brightness controls to work?

Tags: backlight

What do I need to do to get my laptop screen backlight brightness controls to work? I currently have Ubuntu 13.04 and a Dell Studio 1558.

After reading these two links:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061712

I attempted the following, I change the permissions (since I was having errors editing the files)

```
sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

And then I overwrote the file with `1000` (appears `max_brightness` is `4882`)

```
sudo echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

And lo and behold, my screen dimmed.

I've tweaked it before, I'm not sure exactly how, and I don't know why I had to change the permissions on the file again, if I did it that way before.

How can I adjust brightness with the standard keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### xbacklight

```
$ xbacklight +30% # increases brightness by 30 percent
$ xbacklight -30% # decreases brightness by 30 percent
```

#### dbus way

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply \
      --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" \
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
      org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage \
      uint32:<percentage>
```

Example

Set brightness to 30%:

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply \
      --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" \
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
      org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage \
      uint32:30
```

Or
To decrease brightness by a step (~7)

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply \
      --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" \
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
      org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

To increase brightness by a step (~7)

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply \
      --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" \
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
      org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp
```

If it says as follows your OS may be too old. Then use `xdotool`:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: 
Method "SetPercentage" with signature "u" on interface 
"org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen" doesn't exist
```

#### xdotool

- Increase brightness:

  ```
  $ xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
  ```
- Decrease brightness:

  ```
  $ xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
  ```

Comment: Your "dbus way" works only with Gnome (and also if you run gnome-settings-daemon independently, for example with plain window manager such as openbox).

Comment: Accepting because it's the only one :D

Comment: Does it work ?.

Comment: Also See : http://askubuntu.com/questions/409378/changing-brightness-at-startup

Comment: The dbus way gives me this error:

    `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'SetPercentage'`

Comment: I'm on the latest stable GNOME 3.14.2 (Not able to edit the comments above)

Answer (score 2):

Here 2 alternative scripts.

Save it as `brightness_change.sh` and put it in a folder that is part of your $PATH environment variable.
The usage is simple: `brightness_change.sh up` / `brightness_change.sh down`.

You can then assign the script to a keybinding, just take care to specify the full path to the command.

**1. DBUS script ( for gnome )**

I prefer the Dbus approach because :

- you don't need special permission to change the brightness
- the brightness changes done by script are reflected in the brightness applet

Here the script

```
#!/bin/bash
function up(){
    dbus-send --session --type="method_call"  --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp
}

function down(){    
    dbus-send --session --type="method_call" --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" "/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power" "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown"
}

if [[ $1 = "up" ]]
then
     up
elif [[ $1 = "down" ]]
then        
    down
fi
```

**2. Using the /sys/ files**

Using this method requires either you change the permission of the destination file in /sys/ (every boot) either you can had the command to `/etc/sudoers` to require no passwords

I was not sure how to implement the first way so I have added this line to the `/etc/sudoers` ( where fra is my user )

`fra ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/fra/bin/bright_change.sh`

Now you can call the command with sudo without you get prompted for password ( it for sure an hole in the security so take care of that )

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
level=$(cat $file)
inc=100

if [ $level -lt "600" ]
then
    inc=50
fi

function up(){
    newlevel=$(($level+$inc))
    echo $newlevel
}

function down(){    
    newlevel=$(($level-$inc))

    if [ $newlevel -lt "10" ]
    then
        newlevel=1
    elif [ $newlevel -lt "100" ]
    then
        newlevel=10
    fi
    echo $newlevel
}


if [[ $1 = "up" ]]
then
     newlevel=$(up)
elif [[ $1 = "down" ]]
then        
    newlevel=$(down)
fi  


echo $newlevel
# echo $level

echo $newlevel > $file
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I actually didn't do what the accepted answer says. This is a function in my `.bashrc`:

```
bright () { sudo sh -c "echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness " ; }
```

I use it like this -

Full brightness:

```
$ bright 4882
```

About one-tenth brightness:

```
$ bright 482
```

And because the function uses sudo, I have to type in my password, which is ok with me.